# How to Page POST to web page to Print Map with ArcGIS for Server 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, printing

I am using ArcGIS for Server 10.1. I need pass in a lat/long to a webPage as query parameter and print a map with a TiledMapServiceLayer, DynamicMapServiceLayer, and a 1 mile buffer graphic around the lat/lng.  Any ideas how I can do this?

I tried the ESRI javascript API but problem is that I have to let the map render before I print, otherwise this option would work.  I thought about using the REST API by it self and then mashing the images up together, but I am not sure how I would print the buffer graphic.

I need to be able to call a webpage with a query param generate an image because the current SSRS takes the response for the request (a path to the image) and embeds it in the report.  I know it's not the best way to do this, however, I am just trying to modify something that already exists without reworking everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was writing my own c# api that created the json objects needed to send to the PrintTask on GIS Server.  Not really a fun way to do it but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use a Geoprocessing Service that generates your map with a TiledMapServiceLayer, DynamicMapServiceLayer, and a 1 mile buffer graphic around the lat/lng, and then exports it to PDF.